# How to include header.php and footer.php files inside dashboard.php file??? anybody help me?

Tags: php

How to include header.php and footer.php files inside dashboard.php file??? anybody help me?

```
projectname
 - css
 - js
 - include
   - header.php
   - footer.php
 - manager
   - dashboard
     - dashboard.php
   - about
   - contact
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. If you want to include something, then use the `include()` command, I would suggest.

Comment: `../../include/header.php`

Comment: You’ll have to add more information, is this for a specificera cms / plattform?

Answer (score 0):

Use include function

```html
<?php  include '../../include/header.php' ?>
<?php  include '../../include/footer.php' ?>
```